# "Ich fühle mich wohl" and "Ich fühle mich gut"

Tags: word-choice

Is there a difference between *ich fühle mich wohl* and *ich fühle mich gut*? My text book only teaches using "wohl/nicht wohl" and I'm wondering if using 'gut/nicht gut' is also acceptable or not.

Answer (score 6):

These sentences can be used differently. As a German I have experienced the following:

"Sich wohlfühlen" can also be translated to "being comfortable". 
Often it is used to describe a place or something that you do.

"Sich gut fühlen" on the other hand can be helpful to describe how you’re feeling or when you want to say you are motivated.

"Sich nicht gut fühlen" can also be translated to "feeling ill".

There are of course other usages and many of them overlap - as you suggested.

Comment: `sich nicht wohlfühlen` however can never be exchanged with `sich nicht gut fühlen`: the former expresses being uncomfortable with a situation/place, the latter always expresses your health condition.

Answer (score 2):

> ... and I'm wondering if using 'gut/nicht gut' is also acceptable or not.

Both terms are equally well acceptable.

`gut` is a bit stronger than `wohl` in that expression, but the difference is subtle.

It is just the same *"difference"* as in english:

> > I am feeling **well**.

and

> > I am feeling **good**.

Comment: `wohlfühlen` refers to being comfortable (which can also be your health condition), whereas `gut fühlen` refers to anything else (including your health condition). It's exchangable in most cases when used positively - using them negated however makes them far more distinctive.